# Hiding VB.NET extension methods / modules

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, extension-methods

I have a library written in VB.NET containing extension methods. VB.NET has two characteristics that in my opinion are at odds with the concept of extension methods:

- Extension methods must be declared in a module ([Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx))
- All module members are at the namespace scope ([Type Promotion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz7s1h1x.aspx))

This means that extension methods are always either accessible at the namespace level, or not accessible at all. This doesn't make sense, because their scope is conceptually the type they extend, *not* the namespace.

The fact that a method is declared as an extension influences its naming, because while a global utility method might include the type, like `GetDictionaryValueOrNull`, an extension method can simply be `GetValueOrNull` because it should already be clear that it is declared for the `Dictionary` type. When extension methods are global, this can be confusing: Say we are in a (non-Dictionary) class which has a `GetValue` method. If we type "GetValue", Visual Studio will list both "GetValue" and "GetValueOrNull", making it appear as though the current class supports both operations.

Is there any solution to this (other than "write it in C#")? Can I mark a module as non-global, or at least force Visual Studio to only display extension methods *when* they are actually being looked up as extension methods?

Suggestion at Visual Studio User Voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4228049-include-an-option-to-disable-the-promotion-of-scop

Answer (score 0):

The obvious option would be to move your extension methods into a specific namespace, that you only import when you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved all my extension methods to a namespace `*.Extensions`, where `*` is whatever namespace that the *extendee* belongs to. This works even for BCL types, and allows me to import only the extensions I'm interested in while also avoiding a cluttered intellisense.

My only suggestion for distinguishing between utility functions and extension methods is to add xml comments indicating that it is an extension method.

```
''' <summary>(extension) If the dictionary contains the specified key: return its value; otherwise null.</summary>
```